# I want menu close when click on the link

Tags: javascript

I want menu close when click on the link or on ul.
I am using [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sidebar-Slide-In-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3/) menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `active` class whenever an `li` in the `#menu` is clicked like that:

```
$('#menu li').on('click', function() {
    $("#menu,#trigger").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. I appreciate. Just having one issue with the Click Here button it remains active when menu close through click on the li. Would you please fix it so that i can tick your Answer.

Comment: @MohammadKashif Do you want to hide the `Click Here` button when the menu disappears?.. So, how will you show the menu again ?

Comment: Please see this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sidebar-Slide-In-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3/ when menu opens then button active. while in your code menu close on click but button remains active. it should be deactive.

Comment: I did, the `Click Here` button toggles the menu. What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: Please see this jqueryscript.net/demo/Sidebar-Slide-In-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3 when menu opens then button active. while in your code menu close on click but button remains active. it should be deactive.

Comment: @MohammadKashif I updated my answer. Now this will remove the `active` class from both `#menu` and `Click Here` button